# window.open in PHP file not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer

I am having trouble with my PHP webpage at http://lila.godel.com/html/countymp.php.  It worked fine until I upgraded to IE 11.  Now when I click on the View Counties button the correct web page is not opened in a new tab or window based on my browser settings.  Instead the web page just reloads with the radio button selection reset back to the default.

When I tested the web page in another browser it worked correctly.

countymp.php contains the following in the body:

```
<? include("./cmform.php") ?>
```

The code for the cmform.php file may be viewed at http://lila.godel.com/msgfiles/cmform.txt.

If I add a line containing echo "Test"; after the line containing the window.open code in cmform.php clicking the View Counties button correctly results in the webpage reloading with the word Test at the top above the radio buttons.

Any ideas on how to change the code so the form will work correctly in IE 11?

Comment: `window.open()` is disabled by popup blockers when it isn't called in response to a user action. Your code is utterly exactly the same as old-school spammers and is therefore utterly useless in any modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the popup is blocked by IE. You can change settings.